# Where to get messageID in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Where can i get theh messageID in FCM to put in

```
[[FIRMessaging message]sendMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary *)message
                            to:(nonnull NSString *)receiver
                 withMessageID:(nonnull NSString *)messageID
                    timeToLive:(int64_t)ttl;
```

It says that it is a unique message identifier. All the message receiver callbacks are identified on the basis of this message ID.
Here's the link for the FCM [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/upstream).
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the client-side `sendMessage` method the `messageID` parameter is provided by the developer.

You can provide any string you prefer, but you should make sure that it's unique in order to allow your server to uniquely identify (and ack) such message.

A common strategy could be: `message-id = sha1(user-id + timestamp in milliseconds)`
or you can use the FCM token instead of the user-id.